# how to call a if-Statement from another class

Tags: java, function, if-statement, methods, overriding

In this program if-statement is presented which  must be called from an another class with the class name Studentfactory.

```
public class Control {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student[] studs = new Student[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            studs[i] = createStudent();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(studs[i]);
        }
    }

    static Student createStudent() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your name:");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter your age:");
        int age = sc.nextInt();

        if(age <20) {
            return new JuniorStudent(name, age);
        } else if( age < 30) {
            return new IntermediateStudent(name,age);
        }
        return new SeniorStudent(name, age);
    }
}
```

// if statement must b called from this class

```
package demo;

public class Studentfactory {



    }
```

Comment: You call methods, not `if`s. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: What "if statement" do you want to call from another class exactly?

Comment: I can not understand what do you want to do at all. Please describe it more precisely.

Comment: sry sir how to call if statement by method from another class

Comment: which `if` statement do you want to call and from where?

Comment: //This statement I want to delete from this class and add to another class and I just want to call to this class if(age <20) {
            return new JuniorStudent(name, age);
        } else if( age < 30) {
            return new IntermediateStudent(name,age);
        }
        return new SeniorStudent(name, age);
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to call the static method `createStudent` of class `Control` from class `StudentFactory`

The way to do this is

```
Control.createStudent()
```

(in class `StudentFactory`)

Hope this helps!

Comment: sir can u do it briefly

Comment: It's the one line of code shown above. If it doesn't work, it might be because your StudentFactory.java is in a different package than Control.java. Are those classes in the same package?

Answer (score 2):

The `interface` for an "if-statement" would be a `Predicate`, in you case probably `Predicate<Integer>`. You could do something like

```
class AgePredicates {
    public static final Predicate<Integer> isJunior = a -> a < 20;
    public static final Predicate<Integer> isIntermediate = a -> a > 20 && a < 30;
    public static final Predicate<Integer> isSenior = a -> a >= 30;
}
```

and then "call them from a different class" by

```
if (AgePredicates.isJunior.test(age)) {
    // ...
} else if (AgePredicates.isIntermediate.test(age)) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: while this would probably works, OP doesn't seems to understand clearly how class and method work. Predicates may be a too advanced concept at this point.

Comment: bro I don't want to use if in the same class

Comment: @jhamon I agree, I already toned down my answer from using an `enum` instead of a `class` with `static final`s. However, it is the answer that came closest to what I understood of the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is give the age of the `Student` as parameter in your method:

```
static Student createStudent(int age) {  // note the parameter here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your name:");
    String name = sc.nextLine();

    // no sc.nextInt() here anymore
    if(age <20) {
        return new JuniorStudent(name, age);
    } else if( age < 30) {
        return new IntermediateStudent(name,age);
    }
    return new SeniorStudent(name, age);
}
```

By doing so, you can read the next integer from command line somewhere else and just call the method with the next int as parameter. Then the method decides what kind of student is to be created.

**UPDATE**

In your other class that you provided, you would get the age from anywhere (command line, most likely) and then use it as parameter like this:

```
public class Studentfactory {

    public Student createStudentByControl() {
        // create a new Control object
        Control control = new Control();
        // get the age from command line
        int age = sc.nextInt();
        // use the age as parameter for the control to create a new student
        Student student = control.createStudent(age);
        return student;
    }
}
```

Comment: sir I want to if-statement from another class not in the same class

Comment: This is possible by instantiating a new `Control` in another class and then call its method by `control.createStudent(20)` for example.

Comment: tq sir but I'm a beginner can u tell program briefly

Comment: Please edit your question and add the class code where you want to use the decision between the different students.